# What are the advantages of installing vmware tools on a non-gui linux distro?

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

I know this software is usefull when using a gui OS because it adds some features such as auto size screen. But what features are added to a non-gui distro?

Answer (score 3):

Performance improvements for the VM, mostly, as described in the [VMWare](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=340) Knowledge Base article.

Comment: Resubmitted. Tested the link and worked okay.

Comment: Alternatively search with this: "site:VMware.com overview of VMware tools"

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with your link and fixed it, the `http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do` was repeated twice before the useful part of the link causing it to redirect to an error page that said `The requested URL is invalid or internal error occured. Please see your system administrator.`. Removing one of them fixed the link.  Some good info there.